# How can i implement that PivotGrid Telerik Demo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/pivotgrid/index

I want to implement that demo on my basic asp.net mvc project.
But I have an issue with "SampleEntity" and "ProductViewModel" types that are used there. When i've pasted everything they are red. 
Should I make my own implementation of these or wut ? Would be very glad if someone can tell me how to use that demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"When i've pasted everything they are red" -> You don't specify the type of error you're getting. But I suggest you start small by looking at the [Pivot Grid Overview](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/pivotgrid/overview). Then  add on features from there. Remember that the final [Pivot Grid Example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/pivotgrid/index) that Telerik did, includes an array of extra features and code that might be confusing to a new comer, especially if you're not familiar with their controls.